# About using eve for python framework in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, rest, python-2.7, ubuntu-12.04, eve

Just came to know about a project named [python-eve](http://python-eve.org/index.html). As I'm just starting out in python, this project seemed kinda easy to get started for building a python based REST API. This framework really has a lot of features out of the box, specifically `HATEOAS`, which I din't find any built-in way in `google-app-engine` documentation. So is there anyway I can use this framework in `google-app-engine`? Or should I just all together ignore app-engine.

Comment: According to the docs, python-eve runs on mongodb, not app engine.  So the answer should be obvious, unless you're planning to port it over.  And if you are asking this question, it's a safe bet to say that you're not.

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375085/rest-api-in-google-app-engine-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eve is a Flask application, which means that wherever Flask runs, Eve runs... at least in good theory. Check out the following resources:

- [Google App Engine on Flask mailing list](http://flask.pocoo.org/mailinglist/archive/2011/3/27/google-app-engine/#5603a07964fe05029b8074a9314eeab5)
- [Flask Google App Engine template](https://github.com/kamalgill/flask-appengine-template)
- [Flying Flask on Google App Engine](http://f.souza.cc/2010/08/flying-with-flask-on-google-app-engine.html)

I personally have never tried runnning Eve on GAE but the resources above seem to indicate that it should be possible with little effort.

Comment: If you create a default template sort of thing to quickly set up `eve` on `GAE` along with a short tutorial it would be great. Really liked your product specially for the default `HATEOAS` support which seems great and not by default available in `GAE`. Also support for google datastore is not available in `eve`, I guess.

Comment: It isn't but you can always work on it and contribute it to the community :) We currently have people working on SQLAlchemy, CouchDB and other backends. Same with the GAE tutorial, I know somebody is working on a "Eve for the python beginner" tutorial, for example.