# How to access app engine data model from desktop python application?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, raspberry-pi

I am attempting to create a python application on a Raspberry Pi that can access data stored in a db model on an App Engine application. Specifically the latest entry in the data store.

I have no experience doing this type of remote data access but have a fair bit of experience with App Engine and Python.

I have found very little that I understand on this subject of remote data access.

I would like to access the data store directly, not text on a web page like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101742/how-do-you-access-an-authenticated-google-app-engine-service-from-a-non-web-py?rq=1).

[ProtoRPC](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/protorpc/?csw=1) kind of looks like it may work but Im not familiar with it and it looks like it is pretty involved when I just need to access a few strings.

What would make the most sense to accomplish this? If an example is easy to provide I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you looking for is the appengine remote api.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi

Comment: Thanks, I had looked at the Remote API before but for some reason not this specific page which makes a lot of sense for this requirement. I may also have been biased by my previous uses of the remote API for bulk operations only. The [article ](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi) linked from your reference was also informative in describing limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Google App Engine doesn't allow direct access to it's databases from your local python script. Instead, only an application hosted on App engine's server can access that data for your application.

Essentially, you're looking for a Google App Engine compatible, automatic, Restful API. Several exist, and have been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375085/rest-api-in-google-app-engine-python). YMMV with the various frameworks that are discussed there.

Comment: Thanks, I think if I was trying to do something more complex than an few strings this would be worth looking into. Good to know though.